# Javascript, Twitch API call, repeating images/null returns

Tags: javascript, api, debugging, twitch

https://gist.github.com/IllusionElements/ae5427f9675c276f2195 / http://codepen.io/illusionelements/pen/mebZVR the code

Currently  trying to build a twitch api site, that displays users and their streams. Currently I can't seem to figure out why the Online/Offline portions aren't showing up/being added and on this part of the code it seems like everything is returning as null, but when I console.log it not everything will return as null. This is the code:

```
 for (i; i < user.length; i++) {
        str += "<a href='" + url + "'>"
        str += "<div class='row border new'>";
        str += "<img class='col-md-2' id='profile' src='" + logo + "'>"
        str += "<p class='col-md-5'>";
        str += user[i];
        str += "</p>";
        if (streamsObj !== null) { //if this doesn't evalute as null run it, strangely enough it's running as if its all null
          stat.push(streamsObj.channel.status);
          str += "<span class='col-md-5 circle' id='online'>"
          str += "</span>"
          str += "<p class='col-md-12' id='status'>"
          str += stat[i];
          str += "</p>"
        } else if (streamsObj === null) { //Not being run at all here. It's being skipped//
          str += "<span class='col-md-5 circle' id='offline'>"
          str += "</span>"
          str += "<p class='col-md-12' id='status'>"
          str += "Ooops" + " " + user[i] + " " + "is Offline, maybe later?"
          str += "</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very complicated logic but this is happening because the `$.ajax` function runs async http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Because of this when you go and assign the `streamsObj` with a value and then you go and make an `$.ajax` call by the time you get your results in your call the value in `streamsObj` is changed.

If you want to keep your current logic you can use `streamsObj` as an object and have something like an "associative array" where the key will be the username of the user.

So instead of:

```
var streamsObj = twitch.stream;
```

you can have something like:

```
var streamsObj = {} //a global var outside the function
streamsObj['the-username'] = twitch.stream;
```

On the other hand the logic is very complicated now, you create api calls every time the user will want to filter on all, online, offline. Better get the users just once and use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter to filter. For example http://codepen.io/biancamihai/pen/XbXqdM